# Generating the dll file for the solution

Tags: visual-studio, dll, build-process, .net-framework-version

I have got a solution in visual studio .Net (called MyFramework) which contains a big number of projects. When building the whole solution I get the dll files for each of these projects updated though I can not find the dll file MyFramework.dll

It seems like the build process does not generate the dll for the whole solution; i.e. merging all the projects. Does anybody know how can I generate it?

MyFramework.dll is referenced in another ASP.Net solution; so I need the updated dll to be used somewhere else.

note: I'm aware of this utility by Microsoft called [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630) that does that. I was wondering if there are any other simple ways of getting them...

Answer (score 2):

A solution is a structure for organizing projects in Visual Studio. solution is just a container for a set of projects.

Solution files won't generate DLL's combining all the projects inside.  Only project files can generate Dll's, So if you are seeing a MyFramework.dll then there is some other project with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that; though I'm sure there are ways to get the merged dll for the whole solution without having a project called MyFramework.

Comment: There are ways but that is not possible to do that within Visual Studio. You can use ILMERGE http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630 post compilation to achieve this.